# Laravel4 : The requested resource /admin was not found on this server

Tags: php, html, laravel

there is a very weird problem I face with simple Laravel routing.

Because some screenshots, say sometimes more than 1000 words. Here is what I am encountering.

[image: I can't route to "admin"]

[image: It works perfectly fine, if I choose a different name]

[image: And I get a real exception, if the route really does not exist.]

It doesn't matter, if the route is set in laravel or not. It just won't accept the name "admin" and only "admin".  Every other name is routed correctly.

Can't explain this. And wouldn't want to make a fresh laravel installation.

I don't use appache, because "php artisan serve" does the job for me.

Any clues?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

It may that under public you have a folder named admin. That can be source of your problems.

Comment: How can I make without changing the folder name so that route name get priority than the folder name?

Comment: This is quite a common issue and most of the time the problem is having another directory called 'admin' inside the public directory.

Comment: Thanks, was facing same issue in Laravel 9, I was having a folder called "site" in the public directory and was using the same for one of my routes. Changing the name in the public folder immediately solved the issue.

Comment: it happened to me and after i finally read this solution it turns out that you cant have a route name and folder on public directory with the same name. I did not know that since ive never experienced this error before. You live and you learn

Answer (score 6):

In folder public->admin
place these files named

```
.htaccess  
favicon.ico  
index.php  
robots.txt 
web.config
```

like

[image]

and change your `index.php` file in admin folder
from this to
[image]

into this
[image]

hopefully it will solve your problem.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel seem to have some keyword sort of problem. For example the route '/upload' (currenctly using laravel 8) didn't work but changing it to

```
'/uploadImages'
```

work fine.