# Laravel cannot route to /admin

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, admin

I'm starting a new project with Laravel 5.7. I've made standard laravel Auth with artisan. It registered a new route in routes/web.php which is

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

The problem is when i rename '/home' to '/admin' it doesn't work. It returns '*The requested resource /admin was not found on this server.*' error.
I can replace '/home' with anything except '/admin'. Anything else works without a problem.
What is wrong with '/admin' and why can't i use '/admin' as a route?

Comment: Possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031736/laravel4-the-requested-resource-admin-was-not-found-on-this-server

Comment: Check if there is folder name as admin under your public directory.

Comment: Yes, problem is definitely an **admin** folder under **public** folder. Is there a way to force laravel ignore folder structure and only use route rules?

Comment: You cant ignore folders, think of css and js folders. If you want to ignore admin folder you have to edit the .htacces file, but that's another question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel4 : The requested resource /admin was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031736/laravel4-the-requested-resource-admin-was-not-found-on-this-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use this '/admin' route because your project may have 'admin' folder (but not listing file due server config).
Simply rename your admin folder or use '/admin/home' instead.