# '/admin' returns resource not found Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

This is strange because i have this route: `Route::get('/admin',  'AdminController@index');` pointing to `AdminController@index` and the AdminControllers returns `layouts.admin`, it simply doen't work, it keeps returning `404: The requested resource /admin was not found on this server.`, but when I change it to, let's say `Route::get('/administrator',  'AdminController@index');` it works fine!

Can anyone tell me why laravel is giving me that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research and pain I discovered the the problem was that I had `admin` folder under `public` directory as marko stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031920/11299346). The problem gone after removing it.